# Rails 3: converting large arrays to JSON takes nearly 5 seconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, newrelic

assuming we're interpreting this new relic trace correctly, it seems that 4.75s is spent converting large arrays to JSON strings. is this possible? we're not using ruby enterprise edition but ruby 1.9.3.

we're using rails 3.2.12.

the arrays each contain about 1 MB of data and 900 objects.

our interpretation stems from the fact that the last mongo query is the second-to-last line in the method, meaning the red block in the trace represents the last line, which handles rendering and converting arrays to JSONs.

method: https://gist.github.com/panabee/39401fae827ee6aca8bd

[image]

Comment: Why not convert it manually in code to find out if its taking that long. You can then also see how large the resulting JSON blob is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out what's happening, you will need to manually instrument your code using a recursive "divide and conquer" method.

Start by instrumenting in the middle of the code and look at the traces again to determine if the problem is above or below where you instrumented and keep cutting the problem in half until you hit on the problem.

You'll need to add the API calls to your application code and use method tracers.

https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/ruby-custom-metric-collection#method_tracers

Comment: thanks, adam. does this mean our interpretation is wrong, i.e., that it doesn't take 4.75s to execute that one line (the one after the last mongo query)?